# how to use addpeer in ethereum blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum

I am new to ethereum.And could you please tell me the proper use of addpeer to connect two nodes in a single machine.?

Comment: do not forget to add `--nodiscover` flag and also `--maxpeers = 2`

Answer (score 0):

In the first terminal do the following command

```
 admin.nodeInfo.enode
```

It  returns the enode url.Its a unique id for nodes to communicate with each other.

In the second terminal do the `addPeer` command.

```
admin.addPeer(“enode_url_u_just_get_from_the_first_terminal”)
```

To check if the node is successfully added using the following command :-

```
  web3.net.peerCount
```